# uiwebview defined programmatically is not visible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am defining a uiwebview programmatically and its delegate and requests are done but still no visible! why? Thank you

//do some loads on webviewSocial defined on IB and then set it to nil in order to init it after.

```
self.webViewSocial = nil;

self.webViewSocial = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 389)];
self.webViewSocial.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | 
                                       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
[self.webViewSocial setDelegate:self];
[self.vistaSocial addSubview:self.webViewSocial];
```

If I set a new webview it works but problem seems that webviewsocial is set on IB and after this coding is not visible anymore.

Comment: if you remove this "self.webViewSocial.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);" what happens?

Comment: Are you really adding subviews to a `UIWebView?`..If not, you dont need the lines `3+4`.

Comment: also please make sure that "self.vistaSocial" is not null and that self.vistaSocial is added to self.view

Comment: have you  made ​​the connection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some general notes:

- make sure that `self.vistaSocial` is not nil
- make sure that `self.vistaSocial` is added to `self.view`

Also dont release the webView and then reinitialize it
Just change the properties of the existing webView
For example if you want to change the frame of the existing webView and moving it to the new super view, you would do the following

```
self.webViewSocial = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 389);
[self.vistaSocial addSubview:self.webViewSocial];
```

You dont need to release it and reinitialize a new one

Comment: two first points are checked and done properly. I need to realease and init a new one because if not, history is not reset! suggested code only set different frame

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing `webViewSocial` as an IB object since you're actually making it nil then re-initializing it programmatically, it's redundant.

If clearing your browser history is the ultimate goal, try this instead:

```
[webViewSocial stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML = \"\";"];
```

Comment: clear browsing history is my goal but this is not working. What exactly suppose to do?